# Gradle plugin AsciidoctorPdf: Extend font search path

Tags: gradle, asciidoctor-pdf

I want to convert Asciidoctor files into PDF files using Gradle and the AsciidoctorPdf plugin. To be able to customize the resulting PDF, I define a custom theme. As base font I use the EB-Garamond font from Google.

My theme references the default theme, which references the bundled Noto Serif font:
https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/blob/main/data/themes/default-theme.yml

The search path for the bundled fonts is provided by GEM_FONTS_DIR keyword:

> Font paths can be absolute or relative. Absolute paths are used as is. Relative font paths are resolved from the font search path. You can also use the GEM_FONTS_DIR keyword to refer to the location of the bundled fonts.

https://docs.asciidoctor.org/pdf-converter/latest/theme/custom-font/#declare

I set the relative path to the directory containing the EB-Garamond font in the extension of AsciidoctorPdf :

```kotlin
tasks.asciidoctorPdf {
    setFontsDirs(listOf("fonts"))
}
```

Now when I run the build, I get an error message:

```
No such file or directory - notoserif-regular-subset.ttf not found in <absolute-path>/play-books/fonts
Exception in thread "main" org.asciidoctor.gradle.remote.AsciidoctorRemoteExecutionException: Error running Asciidoctor whilst attempting to process <absolute-path>/cocinero.adoc using backend pdf
```

I suspect that by calling setFontsDirs, the search path for fonts is completely reset and thus the path to the bundled fonts is also lost.

How can I pass the path to my own font directory to AsciidoctorPdf without losing the path to the bundled fonts?

build.gradle.kts:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.asciidoctor.jvm.convert")
    id("org.asciidoctor.jvm.pdf")
}

tasks.asciidoctorPdf {
    dependsOn("asciidoctor")

    setFontsDirs(listOf("fonts"))
    setTheme("play-book")
}

pdfThemes {
    local("play-book") {
        themeDir = projectDir
    }
}

tasks.build {
    dependsOn("asciidoctor")
    dependsOn("asciidoctorPdf")
}
```

settings.gradle.kts:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    plugins {
        val versions = object {
            val asciidoctor = "3.3.2"
        }

        id("org.asciidoctor.jvm.convert") version versions.asciidoctor
        id("org.asciidoctor.jvm.pdf") version versions.asciidoctor
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "cartel-deutsch"

include("play-books")
```

play-book-theme.yml:

```yaml
extends: default

font:
  catalog:
    merge: true
    EBGaramond:
      normal: EB_Garamond/static/EBGaramond-Regular.ttf
      italic: EB_Garamond/static/EBGaramond-Italic.ttf
      bold: EB_Garamond/static/EBGaramond-Bold.ttf
      bold_italic: EB_Garamond/static/EBGaramond-BoldItalic.ttf

page:
  size: A5
  margin: [ 8mm, 8mm, 12mm, 8mm ]

base:
  font-family: EBGaramond

heading:
  font-family: Helvetica
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tasks.asciidoctorPdf {
    setFontsDirs(listOf("fonts"))
}
```

> I suspect that by calling setFontsDirs, the search path for fonts is completely reset and thus the path to the bundled fonts is also lost.

This is correct, compare the implementation <sup>1</sup>:

```
    void setFontsDirs(Iterable<Object> paths) {
        this.fontDirs.clear()
        this.fontDirs.addAll(paths)
    }
```

> How can I pass the path to my own font directory to AsciidoctorPdf without losing the path to the bundled fonts?

Two forms, the first is cheating and the second an educated guess.

- cheating 1st: don't. use absolute paths to your fonts when you `merge: true`.
- educated guess 2nd: (not working at time of answer) `setFontsDirs(listOf("fonts", "GEM_FONTS_DIR"))` where the `GEM_FONTS_DIR` is this token verbatim <sup>2</sup>.
- fallback 3rd: There is the other option to also list the default fonts in the YAML and use the GEM_FONTS_DIR prefix there, see  [*Redeclaring the bundle fonts in a custom theme*](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/pdf-converter/latest/theme/font/#extend-catalog) in *Extending the font catalog* <sup>3</sup>.

---

So educated guess was not good enough, Olaf [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76074484/gradle-plugin-asciidoctorpdf-extend-font-search-path#comment134166812_76074906):

> The second suggested solution did not work. GEM_FONTS_DIR is not recognized as a keyword, but as a relative path:
>
> No such file or directory - notoserif-regular-subset.ttf not found in /play-books/fonts:/play-books/GEM_FONTS_DIR

---

1. [/groovy/org/asciidoctor/gradle/jvm/pdf/AsciidoctorPdfTask.groovy#L101-L111](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-gradle-plugin/blob/master/jvm-pdf/src/main/groovy/org/asciidoctor/gradle/jvm/pdf/AsciidoctorPdfTask.groovy#L101-L111)
2. [Configuring the font search path](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/pdf-converter/latest/theme/custom-font/#configure-search-path), specifically this:

   > To include the location of the bundled fonts in the search, include the `GEM_FONTS_DIR` token in the list:
   >
   > ```
   > $ asciidoctor-pdf -a pdf-theme=basic-theme.yml -a pdf-fontsdir="path/to/fonts;GEM_FONTS_DIR" document.adoc
   > ```
3. [Extending the font catalog](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/pdf-converter/latest/theme/font/#extend-catalog)

Comment: The second suggested solution did not work. GEM_FONTS_DIR is not recognized as a keyword, but as a relative path:
No such file or directory - notoserif-regular-subset.ttf not found in <absolute-path>/play-books/fonts:<absolute-path>/play-books/GEM_FONTS_DIR

Comment: Regarding the first proposal, absoulte paths are not a solution because the project will be built in different environments.

Comment: Maybe you can gain it from the environment as the parameter (variable) named `GEM_FONTS_DIR`? It looks a bit like this could be ... and if not, perhaps look it up and provide as absolute path.

Comment: And btw. is it really a relative path you use there `"fonts"`? I can't precisely say why, but  I wouldn't do that, perhaps again only for trouble-shooting reasons. And when everything work, I'd build back then.

Comment: @Olaf: There is the other option to also list the default fonts in the YAML and use the GEM_FONTS_DIR prefix there, see _Redeclaring the bundle fonts in a custom theme_ in _Extending the font catalog_. It is perhaps a bit awkward, but maybe better than creating symbolic links when setting up the environments (which could also work). YMMV.

Comment: Your suggestion works. I have repeated the font declarations of the default theme. Doesn't feel really good though. But it works and that counts.

Comment: @Olaf: I've added it as the third option to the answer. It is perhaps worth to ask for GEM_FONTS_DIR support for the gradle plugin.